# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'. sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_PostVisitCountInsert](
@postCount bigint,
@postID bigint)
as
 Begin
  if not exists(select * from PostVisitCount where postID=@postID)
   Begin
    Insert into PostVisitCount(postcount,postID) values(@postCount, @postID)
   end   
  else
    Begin
     --Query for Update PostVisitCount
       Declare @count bigint
       Set @count=(select postcount from PostVisitCount where postID=@postID)
       Update PostVisitCount set postcount=(@count+1), postID=@postID
    End 
 end --Error getting at this place
```

When I try to execute the query, I'm getting error with these query. I don't understand what is wrong with this query any one helps me to figure out what did I do wrong.

Comment: please post the entire query,so that some one can parse and help

Comment: Do you have an Update-query, or is there only this comment? The Begin and End statements cannot be empty; a statement needs to be between Begin and End.

Comment: @TheGameiswar : i added update query to its not working showing same error

Comment: I dont see any issue with your updated code,it successfully parses for me with out any error

Comment: i'm getting this error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure proc_PostVisitCountInsert, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'End'.

Comment: There are some logic/style issues in your else, but no syntax errors that I can see. (Your else should probably just be the single statement `update PostVisitCount set postcount = postcount + 1 where postID = @postID`)

Comment: its working, i deleted old stored procedure and created new then its working

Answer (score 1):

The Begin End for ELSE does not contain any statement (it is actually commented out). That is the reason for the error. The following will work

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_PostVisitCountInsert](
@postCount bigint,
@postID bigint)
as
 Begin
  if not exists(select * from PostVisitCount where postID=@postID)
   Begin
    Insert into PostVisitCount(postcount,postID) values(@postCount, @postID)
   end   
  else
    Begin
     Query for Update PostVisitCount
    End 
 end --Error getting at this place
```

Comment: If that was the case (and I admit that was my initial thought as well), the error would have been raised one row before.

Comment: Can you post the full code you used?

Comment: i've posted full code which i'm using

Answer (score 0):

@user6503334: I am not sure whether my post would fix your issue but you can change the "else" part like the below since I felt there is something logically missing in your update statement. I have done a couple of changes in the else part. You should add where clause otherwise all the rows would be updated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_PostVisitCountInsert] (
    @postCount BIGINT
    ,@postID BIGINT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM PostVisitCount
            WHERE postID = @postID
            )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PostVisitCount (
            postcount
            ,postID
            )
        VALUES (
            @postCount
            ,@postID
            )
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --Query for Update PostVisitCount
        DECLARE @count BIGINT

        SET @count = (
                SELECT sum(postcount) + 1
                FROM PostVisitCount
                WHERE postID = @postID
                )

        UPDATE PostVisitCount
        SET postcount = @count
        WHERE postID = @postID
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the one valid answer was given in a comment and not everybody reads those, the script should look like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_PostVisitCountInsert](
    @postCount bigint,
    @postID bigint
)
as
Begin
    if not exists (select * 
        from PostVisitCount 
        where postId = @postId)
    Begin
        insert into PostVisitCount(postcount,postID) values(@postCount, @postID)
    end        
    else
    Begin
        --Query for Update PostVisitCount
        update PostVisitCount set postcount = postcount + 1 where postID = @postID
    End 
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably this should work.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_PostVisitCountInsert](
@postCount bigint,
@postID bigint)
as
 Begin
  if not exists(select * from PostVisitCount where postID=@postID)

    Insert into PostVisitCount(postcount,postID) values(@postCount, @postID)
  else

     --Query for Update PostVisitCount

 end --Error getting at this place
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the Begin and End in the first IF branch, and I would not have an empty ELSE like this.